# storing ip address or geo data for it

Tags: php

**Forenote**

*This is a web application being written in PHP/etc*

---

This will be a rather rhetorical question about the best practice/most effective way to go about this issue.

Basically, I've been handed a little task. With each post that gets posted to this app, it needs the geo information of the poster's IP address. The reason I asked this question is that this app has the potential to grow exponentially, very quickly and I don't want a silly bottleneck like this causing any issues.

I've thought of 2 possible options to handle getting the GEO Information (*based off the IP Address*) as below.

- Store the IP Address and run it against an IP address info.

Example of the above being something like:

```
$ip = '127.0.0.1'; // derp
$url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?key=API_KEY&format=json&ip=". $ip; // or other api's, etc...

$info = file_get_contents($url); // or use curl etc..
$data = json_decode($info);

//....itterate through results of $data and use as required
```

Or would it be best

- As the post is submitted, Run the api call to get the geo location for said ip address, then store the required information in the data-set along with the post.

Example:

```
id | post_id | ip | lat | long | country | state | zip | .....etc
```

Or is there another way that you would do it / could do it? Open to any suggestions you have :)

Comment: 3. Retrieve GEO data asynchronously in a separate worker

Comment: @zerkms Interesting. Would I be doing that on server side or client side?

Comment: do you realize that you cannot trust the data received from a client?

Comment: PHP is synchronous by definition. To perform an asynchronous request you'll need to use AJAX

Comment: @scrowler: one could add a task to the queue and process it by workers server-side without any AJAX. Another point: we don't even know if it's a web application, not, say, a native android one.

Comment: @zerkms Apologies, it is a web application written with PHP. Unfortunately, I'm only tasked with fetching the said GEO info for the IP address attached to the post.

Comment: @Darren: "Unfortunately, I'm only tasked with fetching the said GEO info for the IP address attached to the post" --- if the solution was already decided for you by your supervisor or a tech lead, then what your question is about? The better solution is to do it asynchronously. That is.

Comment: @zerkms Could you possibly throw up an example/pseudo code and I'll accept it. Cheers

Comment: @Darren There is no generic solution for "do it asynchronously".

Comment: @zerkms Then last question, would I be on the right path using something like [Pheanstalk](https://github.com/pda/pheanstalk/) or [`pcntl_fork()`](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php) ?

Comment: @Darren: RabbitMQ and some custom code around it.

Comment: Its going to be more performant at high scale to just buy the IP->GEO database. Then you don't have to store it for each record, you can look it up at will with a regular JOIN, if of course thats within budget.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To close this question off, I went with using [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) as **zerkms** [stated in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25194943/storing-ip-address-or-geo-data-for-it#comment39235351_25194943).

Essentially wrapping it in a little bit of custom code and storing it as the following:

```
id | post_id | ip | lat | long | country | state
```